# how to return a value back to a different class once Network stream recieves it c# (message chat)

Tags: c#

I'm having a hard time naming this question and solving my problem.

I'm challenging myself in creating a chat server with multiple chat clients.

I've created a server that instantiates a new `ClientManager` object upon receiving a new connection via TCP. I'm missing various bits of management currently so ignore that as I'm focusing on figuring this bit out first:

Once the connection is established the `ClientManager` creates a new background worker for receiving streams. What I'm having trouble is once the stream is read, how can I forward that information back to my main server class to distribute amounts to the other clients (chat clients).

Once again, I'm missing a few management options such as threading, semaphores, etc but that will come as I build it out.

Here is how my server established a connection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ChatServer
{
    class Program
    {
        private IPAddress localAddr;
        private int serverPort;
        private BackgroundWorker bwListener;
        private List<ClientManager> clients;

        private TcpListener server;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program progInstance = new Program();
            progInstance.clients = new List<ClientManager>();

            progInstance.server = null;
            try
            {
                // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
                progInstance.serverPort = 13000;
                progInstance.localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

                // Start to listen
                progInstance.bwListener = new BackgroundWorker();
                progInstance.bwListener.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                progInstance.bwListener.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(progInstance.ServerListen);
                progInstance.bwListener.RunWorkerAsync();

            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for new clients.
                //progInstance.server.Stop();
            }


            Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }

        private void ServerListen(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            this.server = new TcpListener(this.localAddr, this.serverPort);
            this.server.Start();
            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... \n");
                Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();
                this.AcceptClientConnection(client);
            }
        }


        private void AcceptClientConnection(Socket client) {

            ClientManager newClient = new ClientManager(client);
            this.clients.Add(newClient);
        }

        private void DisplayClientConnections() {

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the ClientManager

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ChatServer
{
    class ClientManager
    {
        NetworkStream stream;
        private Socket socket;
        private BackgroundWorker bwReceiver;
         //data = null;
        public ClientManager(Socket socket)
        {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.stream = new NetworkStream(this.socket);
            this.bwReceiver = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.bwReceiver.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(StartReceive);
            this.bwReceiver.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void StartReceive(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            String data = null;
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            int i;
            while (this.socket.Connected) {            
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking that the server should somehow retrieve this information and then write it to the stream, or would I just do that would I just write back to the stream from the `ClientManager` and then have my actual clients listen and receive? I'm just super lost how to handle this portion of the chat server.